# how to find the frequency of a word aftr sorting inpython

Tags: python

I have a txt file from which i want to calculate the frequency of each
word, after that i want to sort the list and after sorting i want to 
print the frequencies in descending order with their relevant word. I 
write python code but i m out of mind how to do this. code is

```
frequency = []
file = open("C:/Python26/rzlt.txt");
contents=file.read();
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(contents);
f=open("frequencies.txt",'w')
f2=open("count.txt",'w')
for t in tokens:
    freq = str(tokens.count(t))
    frequency.append(freq)
    f.write(t+"\t"+freq)
frequency.sort(reverse=True)
for t in tokens:
    f2.write(t+"\t"+ frequency(t))
f.close()
f2.close()
```

Comment: Why are you using nltk for this?

Comment: I know its not necessary

Comment: actual problem is in last for loop through which i want to save the descending list of frequency with the relevant token

Comment: Why first count and then sort? That's overly complicating things. I have a feeling you're not even nearly giving us as much details on the problem as you should.

Comment: ok, my actual problem that i have to solve is that i have to print the tokens of a txt file with their relevant frequencies but in descending order.

Answer (score 1):

`with open() as .. :` automatically closes file. `collections.Counter()` counts all words in your list.

Finally `sorted()` sorts the `Counter()` object in descending value order.

```
import collections

with open('my_text_file.txt', 'r') as f:

    f_as_lst = f.read().split()
    c = collections.Counter(f_as_lst)

# Creates a list of tuples with values and keys swapped
freq_lst = [(v, k) for k, v in c.items()]
# Sorts list by frequency
freq_lst = sorted(freq_lst, key=lambda item: item[0])

print freq_lst
```

---

In case you cant use `collections.Counter()`, you can use the following function to replace it:

```
def my_counter(list_of_strings):    
    dct = {}

    for string in list_of_strings:
        if string not in dct:
            dct.update({string: 1})
        else:
            dct[string] += 1

    return dct
```

Comment: cause of problem that is       AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Counter'

Comment: @ShaheenGul It works perfectly fine in my files. Are you sure you copied the code correctly? Also, show the full error here so that i can check it out.

Comment: I m using the python version 2.6 which does not import the counter()

Comment: @ShaheenGul Updated answer with a function that can replace `collections.Counter()`.

Comment: I have to print the list of tokens with their frequencies, but in descending order

Comment: @ShaheenGul Edited code, try it and let me know if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 1):

try like this: use the Counter

```
import nltk
from collections import Counter
file = open("C:/Python26/rzlt.txt");
contents = file.read();
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(contents);
words = map(str.isalnum, tokens)
frequency = Counter(words)

for x, y in sorted(frequency.items(), key=lambda x:x[1]):
    print x, y
```

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name Counter  problem

Comment: which version of python you susing??

Answer (score 1):

```
Try This, I had used collections for getting the count of the each word,
and for displaying it in ascending ordered i used sorted with parameter
reverse=True  

import collections      ## import the collection module 
file = open("filename.txt")     ## open the file which need to be sorted
list = []                       ## Create the empty list
print "sorted data : "          
print "==============================================="
for data in file:                ## Iterate the data file 
    list.append(data.strip())
print "\n".join(sorted(list)) ## Print each read line on next line
count = collections.Counter(list)    ## Get the count of the each word 
print "==============================================="
print "Count of each word is:"
for data in sorted(count, reverse=True):        ## Iterate the file in ascending order
    print '%s : %d' % (data, count[data])    ## Print the read file in ascending order
```

Comment: i m using python version 2.6 which does not import the counter and caused a problem. My above code is accurate, only the problem is in displaying of frequencies(reverse ordered) with the relevant token. suggest the solution for my this problem only

Comment: suggest only a solution that will  display the frequencies with their relevant token. In my code tokens of the txt files are in tokens list and frequency contains the sorted values . only problem is in displaying of them

Comment: may i know why you are using nltk??? What is the specific use of it? the above suggested solution have you seen that working or not???

Comment: problem is in use of counter(). bcoz me using python 2.6

Comment: and i have to print both token and frequency of that token in descending order